# Searching by Managed Metadata

Tags: document-library, search, search-query

Currently I have a document library with multiple views and tabbed using hillbilly tabs, the find a file function is not working for me for some reason.

The library has a managed metadata field and I have added a search box and results above the tabbed libraries.

The search is working the way I need it to with the search box and results page but I would like to know how to add the managed metadata field to the query.  Currently, it seems as if the search box is only looking at the text of the document not the information from the form fields.  I would like both if possible.

Here is my query:

[image]

Thanks.